# Which is the Charset java uses to store strings internally?

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

Using the method `String.getBytes(Charset cs)` we can turn a string into a byte array with respect to a certain encoding. But before doing that the string is already stored at some point in our random access memory. Which charset is used here?

Comment: an interesting discussion - http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/1/9/ucs-vs-utf8/

Answer (score 3):

Java strings using an array of `char`s, which are UTF-16.

Comment: I'll add that that is an implementation detail of the current java release.

Comment: proof or it didn't happen.

Comment: @EduardoDennis: http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#114